# I got the following error when I run a command with htdocs xampp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

I got the following error when I run a command with Htdocs xammp

`'C:\xampp\htdocs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: What command are you trying to run?

Comment: i want to install Laravel 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Install composer. In case it is not yet installed here is the easiest way to [install composer on windows](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer)

2 - Go to your htdocs folder through the command line and run this command: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name` . This will create a new folder `project-name`

3 - Access the `project-name` folder through the command line and run `php artisan serve`

4 - Open your browser and access `http://localhost:8000`